# pre-request скрипт в postman

Tags: postman

Есть большая необходимость реализовать такой функционал, что бы перед отправкой запроса к api, тело запроса подписывалось с помощью ключа(ключ имеется в виде файла), и сгенерированная подпись устанавливалась бы в Headers в качестве X-Signature Key. Возможно ли в postman организовать подобный сценарий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую такой скрипт:

```
const sign = CryptoJS.SHA256(pm.request.body.raw + "ключ").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
pm.request.headers.upsert({
    key:'X-Signature Key',
    value: sign
});
```

Соответственно вместо "ключ" нужно подставить свой секретный ключ